# Switch case auto indentation to enable folding on VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, switch-statement

I am using Visual Studio Code, and in one of my projects I have a huge switch-case statement that I want to be able to read through easily by collapsing individual `case '...':` statements.

By doing research, I've found that I had to change **Folding Strategy** from `auto` to `indentation` in the settings to be able to fold cases individually. This works wonder like in this example :

```js
switch (cmdPrimary) {
   case 'help':
      // code
   break;
   case 'ping':
      // code
   break;
}
```

[This is how it looks like in the editor with folding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTPBD.png)

However, now, whenever I use the auto-indentation, VSCode changes my code to look like this :

```js
switch (cmdPrimary) {
   case 'help':
   //code
   break;
   case 'ping':
   //code
   break;
}
```

[This is how it looks like in the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPHY6.png)

As you can see, I can no longer fold my individual cases because auto-indentation actually removed the indentation that each cases' code had.

I don't really care about the indentation of my code as long as I can fold cases individually.

Is there any way I could either make auto-indentation work differently for switch-cases, or just let VSCode fold individual cases without using Folding Strategy to `indentation` ?

Thanks a lot for any answer.

Comment: For me the `break` statement and preceding code is not re-formatted flush left with the `case` statement.  You may have a formatter (prettier?) that is doing that.  Try disabling prettier or other formatter and see if your indentation is better and folding controls remain.

Comment: @Mark My Visual Studio Code installation is extremely recent, and I didn't install anything related to it for now. I tried with one installed, and uninstalled it afterwards, and it didn't change anything. Also to note that this behaviour is present on the three differents setups I use to code, where all three have different settings.